# Problema ao armazenar valores decimais no SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework

Tenho um campo decimal(18, 3) e na aplicação uso um plugin em JavaScript para formatar os valores digitados, então eu passo o valor assim pro SQL Server 45.000.000.000, quando olho o que foi cadastrado foi isso 45000000000.000, ou seja, ele colocou 3 zeros a mais, ele intende como se eu não tivesse passado os valores das casas decimais. Já tentei fazer a mascara no padrão americano, e no padrão brasileiro.

Qual seria a melhor forma de resolver isso? Como vocês fazem nessa situação?

---Editado---

Estou usando entity framework,esse é o código no Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
public decimal VlrObra { get; set; }
```

Código na classe de acesso a dados

```
public void Salvar(Obra obra)
{
    db.Obra.Add(obra);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Você já tentou enviar como 45.000.000,000?

Comment: Sim, ele faz a mesma coisa. Alias de inicio tava assim, depois eu mudei para o padrão americano pra ver se podia ser isso.

Comment: Qual o código utilizado para fazer essa inserção? Pode por favor colocar na pergunta?

Comment: Mas você mandou salvar `45.000.000.000` e quando faz o SQL aparece `45000000000.000`. Se for isto está correto, pois o retorno colocou os decimais. Mas se você mandou `45.000.000`, então está errado. Tenta enviar `45.000.000.000,123` e vê o que retorna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique se seu `Web.config` possui a seguinte declaração:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
    ...
</system.web>
```